# execute sql statement in asp.net mvc3 (C#)

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

How to execute sql statement in asp.net mvc3 (C#)? I am using Entity Data Model for my asp.net mvc application

I need to execute a sql query ("`select * from users where EmailAddress like '%@gmail.com'`").

Comment: Look into NHibernate or DAL Wrappers.

Comment: Use an `SqlConnection` to execute the `SqlCommand`. Ideally this should be done in the Model, which in turn is called by an action in the Controller.

Comment: do you not have a User Entity?

Comment: Yes I have that entity, but i need this to achieve a particular scenario where the admin can filter the users based on custom query(like advanced search). When the admin uses advanced search, i can construct a query and trying to execute and get the results

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is your `User` entity mapped? In such case yo can use

```
var users = from u in context.Users
            where u.EmailAddress.EndsWith("@gmail.com")
            select u;
```

If you don't have `User` table mapped but you have `User` class with parameterless constructor and public settable properties with same names as columns in result set you can use:

```
var users = context.ExecuteStoreQuery<User>("select * from users where EmailAddress like '%@gmail.com'");
```

in case of ObjectContext API or:

```
var users = context.Database.SqlQuery<User>("select * from users where EmailAddress like '%@gmail.com'");
```

If you don't have entity you can execute it as any other ADO.NET command by creating `SqlConnection`, `SqlCommand` and calling `ExecuteReader` on the command.

Comment: Can we join multiple tables with ExecuteStoreQuery?

Comment: You can excute any SQL query with that method, so you can join tables as well.

Comment: Can you execute a query this way on multiple tables?